# Given $T : \mathbb{R}^{100} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{100}$ linear transformation what is true for sure? (options added)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am having a difficult to understand why for a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^{100} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{100}$. What is true in 100% from the following options:

a) $\ker(T) \subseteq \operatorname{im}(T)$

b) $\ker T \cap \operatorname{im} T \neq \varnothing$

c) $ker(T) \neq \operatorname{im}(T)$

d) $ker(T) =  \operatorname{im}(T)$

According to the book, the answer is $b$ and I don't understand why. the first counter example that come up in my mind is the identity operator. this means that the only vector in the intersection of the image and the kernal is the zero vector

Comment: $0\not = \varnothing$.

Comment: @anomaly I think you mean $\{0\} \ne \emptyset$, eh?

Comment: @sagigever, you should find counter-examples to each of the other answers to firm up your understanding. For example `d)` is trivially false if you take $T(\vec{x})=\vec{0} \forall \vec{x}\in\Bbb{R}^{100}.$

Comment: @anomaly as I suspected, I misinterperted the sign of $\phi$ thank you for clarifying that

Comment: @Chickenmancer: That too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the counter examples for options a, c and d and proof of b.
a) Consider the map $T:\mathbb R^{100}\rightarrow \{0\}$. Here, $ker(T)=R^{100}$ and $im(T)=\{0\}$. So, $ker(T)\nsubseteq im(T)$.
b) There is a common element namely $0\in R^{100}$ in both $ker(T)$ and $img(T)$.
c) Consider the map
$T((x_1,x_2,...x_{100}))=
\begin{cases}
(0,0,...,0)\in \mathbb R^{100}, & \text{if $x_{51}=0,x_{52}=0,...,x_{100}=0$ } \\
(x_{51},x_{52},...,x_{100},0,0,...,0) \in \mathbb R^{100} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
Observe/prove that T is linear transformation.
$ker(T) = {(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{50},0,0,...,0)}$ and
$img(T)={(y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{50},0,0,...,0)}$.
So, $ker(T)=img(T)$.

d) Consider the map T(x)=0. Here $ker(T)=R^{100}$ and $im(T)=0\in R^{100}$